# "javac: release version 10 not supported" during compile

Tags: java, compiler-errors, javac

Complete noob to Java compilation here. Wanted to build [filebot](https://github.com/filebot/filebot) for personal usage.

### Setup

The build script I'm using is, from [here](https://github.com/Phoenix09/filebot/commit/e9e9582510d985ab1af61b77a5a0efb7d18dd3d6):

```
@echo off
cd /D %~dp0
set PATH=%WIX%\bin;%PATH%

if not defined JAVA_HOME (set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4)

echo Downloading dependencies...
call ant resolve

echo:

echo Compiling...
call ant fatjar

echo:

echo Building MSI installer...
call ant msi

if not defined WORKSPACE pause
```

I have installed WiX Toolset, Apache Ant, Apache Ivy, and JDK 9.0.4 (as the original filebot has stopped using JDK 8). Added the Ant/bin folder to user path, and copied ivy.jar to that folder. Also set JAVA_HOME to jdk folder.

Worth noting, I had jre9.0.4 earlier, and installed jdk on top of that. After some googling, found that jre also copies some files to System32 folder, and that the remedy is to have jdk/bin folder as the topmost entry in Path variables. But this has not solved the error.

### Error

The main problem that I'm facing is that, after downloading the dependencies, during the Compilation stage, I get the following output:

```
[javac] Compiling 395 source files to D:\Misc\filebot\build
[javac] javac: release version 10 not supported  // I believe this is the culprit
[javac] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
[javac] use --help for a list of possible options

BUILD FAILED
```

And after this, the msi build also fails. The relevant `build.xml` part is:

```
<javac srcdir="${dir.source}" destdir="${dir.build}" release="${jvm.version}" encoding="utf-8" debug="yes" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" includeAntRuntime="no">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${dir.dist}/lib" />
    </classpath>
</javac>
```

I could not find any relevant info about the `version 10 not supported` part on Google, and also haven't installed jdk 10.

`javac -version` gives `javac 9.0.4`

I'm very new to Java compilation, and may have missed something trivial. TIA :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I thought, I'd missed something trivial. filebot has moved to jdk 10, which is why the error was being shown when I was trying to compile with jdk 9.

So, to anyone facing a similar problem, make sure the target JDK of the source you're building is the same as your development kit version.

Comment: please elaborate on "target jdk of the source" - how do i find out what this is?

Comment: @notacorn Literally, the error shows the target jdk: `version xyz not supported`. You need to install that JDK version `xyz` in your system